# I am part of your body

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I am part of your body.
>   Without my head, I can live in the forest.
>   Without my tail, I will be something a ball can do.
>   And without my head and my tail, You must remember me.

What am I?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think it is

> SPINE

Without my head, I can live in the forest.

> PINE

Without my tail, I will be something a ball can do.

> SPIN

And without my head and my tail, You must remember me.

> PIN

Answer (score 6):

I know this is answered already, but I wanted to take a stab at another answer:

I am part of your body.

> THROAT

Without my head, I can live in the forest.

> OAT — Wild oats *could* grow in a sparse forest

Without my tail, I will be something a ball can do.

> THRO (or *throw*) — A ball is often made to be thrown

And without my head and my tail, You must remember me.

> O (or *oh*) — [Mirriam-Webster's 3rd definition of "oh"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oh) is "`used to express acknowledgment or understanding of a statement`". The example they provide is "`Oh, yes. It's one of my favorite cities.`" Doesn't seem like *too* much of a stretch...